# Excel Macro to match and concatenate data into a single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I've had a hunt around for some macros that might be able to do this, however my expertise is just about good enough that I can understand what's going on in other answers but sadly not yet good enough to modify the proposed solution to suit my needs. This, of course would be avoided if I could use an updated version of excel with the new `TextJoin` function.

I currently have data in multiple sheets all of which is related. For example:

**Sheet 1**

```
      A            B            C        
ROW   1 Red       url1            comment 1
ROW   2 Orange    url1            comment 2
ROW   3 Yellow    url2            comment 3
ROW   4 Green     url3            comment 4
```

**Sheet 2**

```
      A            B            C        
ROW   1 Red-Bike     url1         comment 1-1
ROW   2 Red-Car      url1         comment 1-2
ROW   3 Orange-Bike  url1         comment 1-3
ROW   4 Yellow-Bike  url2         comment 2-1
ROW   5 Green-Bike   url3         comment 3-1
```

The comments from the rows where urls match across sheets need to be concatenated into a third sheet like so:

**Sheet 3**

```
        A            B               C
ROW 1   url1         comment 1       comment 1-1
                     comment 2       comment 1-2
                                     comment 1-3

ROW 2   url2         comment 3       comment 2-1

ROW 3   url3         comment 4       comment 3-1
```

Comment: you can use `vlookup`